Is “reduct” just another word for “image through a forgetful functor”?
I have just started learning Mathematical Logic in greater depth and I was assigned some lecture notes to read.
I noticed how the lecturer often used the word reduct, to mean… a structure which has gone through a transformation, I guess.
I’ll give you one example: he had just finished introducing Gödel Algebras, and in particular the one whose carrier set is $[0; 1]$, and he called it $[0; 1]_G$, to refer to the whole structure, comprising of the top and bottom element, together with the conjunction, disjunction, implication and negation operators.
He then gave the following proposition:

$[0; 1]_G$ is the only Gödel Chain (a Gödel algebra which is also linearly ordered) with the lattice reduct $\big ( [0;1], \, \max, \, \min, 0, 1 \big )$.

It took me a few seconds to understand this statement, but since I’m acquainted with Category Theory I restated the thing in my mind as follows:

The Class (Category) of Gödel Algebras has a natural forgetful functor towards the Category of Bounded Lattices. Then, the fibre through this functor of the lttice $\big ( [0;1], \, \max, \, \min, 0, 1 \big )$ is a singleton, namely the Gödel Algebra $[0; 1]_G$.

Similar statements appear multiple times in the notes.
I went to Wikipedia and found out that reducts aren’t just an informal term, but they are indeed a thing in Logic and Model Theory! (Sorry, I’m not an expert in these two fields).
But it seems to me that reduct is just another word for the image, through a forgetful functor.
Is it really so? Is it just to-mey-to/to-mah-to for Algebraists and Logicians, or is there something deeper I’m missing here?

You could see "reduct" as a particular implementation (in the context of universal algebra) of the informal notion of forgetful functor, yes. I wouldn't be surprised if the notion of reduct predated the notion of functor.

Forgetful functor is not formally defined, reduct is.

Reducts are examples of forgetful functors, but there are other examples. The operation that sends any model of (say) Peano Arithmetic $(A,+,\times,0,1)$ to $(A,+,Q)$, where $Q$ is the set of squares in $A$, isn't a reduct, because $Q$ isn't part of the structure  $(A,+,\times,0,1)$, but it is a forgetful functor between suitable categories of models. [$(A,+,Q)$ is a reduct of a definitional expansion of $(A,+,\times,0,1)$, and some people use "reduct" with this more genneral meaning.]

Erm, why are you posting answers in the comment section? What comments are is explained here, as you know they should not be used for giving answers, and there are many reasons for this rule. Even the placeholder in the comment textbox mentions this.

Thank you, @MartinBrandenburg, for pointing this out! Actually, as OP, I considered some of the comments a very satisfying answer, so I wanted to give them a green tick and possibly close the thread! Unfortunately, I can’t, exactly because the answers I like are… comments!
